# Possible to add a checkBox to SWT Group Border

Tags: java, swt, border

I want a SWT Border with radio Button, so using Group with some text name.
But I want to provide a radio button prefix to the group name border.
Is it possible?
[image: Radio Button infront Group]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default this is not possible. The [opal project](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/) has something similar with Checkboxes, see [here](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/Checkboxgroup)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overlaying your radio button on group using the `FormLayout`.